# Waiting between meat and a product with negligible dairy

Tags: meat-and-milk, bitul-batel-null

After eating meat, there's a strong custom to wait a while before eating dairy, but does this apply if the dairy (or meat) food contained an amount of dairy/meat that, if it fell into the first food by accident, would have been "batul"?

For example, let's say that soon after I ate meat, I want to eat a food that is less than one-sixtieth dairy, and that dairy ingredient cannot be tasted (but was nonetheless mixed in deliberately). May I do so?

Comment: If it fell in meat wouldn't the meat be kosher? So why would you have to wait?

Comment: @DoubleAA that's only if it fell in by accident. Here, the dairy was mixed into the second food intentionally, and the person who will be eating it knows about the diary as well

Comment: If it is an item with only pareve ingredients but was cooked in clean milky keilim you do not have to wait after meat, but should not eat it with meat on the same plate. In your case though if the milk was deliberately added that would not apply

Comment: @CashCow thanks, but can you tell me how you know that, and why that would be the case? As doubleAA noted, if the milk fell in by accident the mixture would be allowed to be eaten

Comment: @Matt It wasn't mixed in to be nullified. (Incidentally, "texture" might qualify as Maamid, and then you have problems.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure what you mean to say (though you're right about texture, though I think most assume it's not a Davar haMaamid; I wasn't sure what a better example would be... To make it inedible to someone allergic to dairy?)

Comment: I'm saying there is no problem here with mevatel issur lechatchila bc no one is trying to mevatel it (and then kol shekein to heter).

Comment: @DoubleAA that's exactly the question; I'm not sure if that's true. Maybe my decision to eat the mixed food, at a time when it's prohibited for me to eat diary, counts as a mental bittul (or something like that)

Comment: @DoubleAA according to you, could I take the less-than-one-in-sixty-dairy food and eat it with meat, lechatchilah? Is the food diary already batul because it was mixed in b'heter, or is "eating together" a new mixture? Perhaps I should've asked that question

Comment: @Matt It sounds like now you're asking if you need to know about a mixture and intend for bittul to apply for it to apply. That's not obvious. Bittul may just happen once they are mixed. See Rama 109:2 and 99:6 about how Noda' HaTaarovet affects application of Bittul.

Comment: Please refine the question to reflect what it is you're really looking to learn.

Comment: @SethJ when I have time I'll ask another question based on the comments here, but for now can't the question stand? Is it unclear? It's a simple "is this allowed" question, and it's even been answered by the Maadanei Shulchan

Comment: The fact that someone answered a multi-layered Halachic question doesn't make the question posted here any clearer. As you can see, both from the Teshuvah and the discussion in the comments above, this is a pretty complex question, so it pays to be clear. I think it's pretty clear, but I think the comments above were just trying to weed out exactly what you mean to be asking.  If what you posted is still what you had in mind, I think it's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The seffer Maadanei HaShulchan in סימן פ׳ט s.v. 33 & 34  says that the תבשיל של בשר and תבשיל של גבינה which are subject to the minhag to be treated as real meat and milk as far as waiting goes, are specifically referring to תבשיל which do not have ששים and therefore do have טעם of whichever מין Is under discussion.

At a surface glance he does not seem to directly source this idea from earlier works.

But it seems that this is assumed. See Beis Yosef Orach Chaim 173 in the name of Rabeinu Tam who explains תבשיל של בשר as only having טעם. He also quotes הגהות מיימוני using this idea and saying therefore רוטב של בשר which is מושך טעם would be problematic. This point is brought in Taz in Yoreh Deah ad loc #5.

Comment: I looked in the Badei HaShulchan and did not find a stringent opinion regarding this issue. If he doesn't bring a stringent opinion, you can safely assume one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

When explaining the concept of *batel bshishim* and *ain mevatel l'chatchilah*, the star-k gives the sources and explanations of these concepts. [UNDERSTANDING BATEL B’SHISHIM (One-Sixtieth)](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-ABISSELBITUL.htm) However, the article deals with the actual mixing and whether or not it is kosher. The case given in the question could be derived from the analysis. Since the dairy (or meat) is **not** nullified, it is treated as if the second product is fully dairy (or meat). **Thus, just as the mixture is asur, the second product must not be eaten within the forbidden time period.**

However, based on the details of the case and the specific circumstances in the involved, there are various leniences that can be applied. However, the case as the OP describes it does not appear to have those leniences. For example, the description of "[Dairy Equipment](http://www.cor.ca/view/183/what_does_dairy_equipment_mean.html) shows that while it can be eaten after a meat meal, it is **not** the case of the question.

The answers which deal with nonkosher also explain the circumstances that would apply with meat and dairy and when **intensional** bitul will apply. That is, just as putting a drop of milk into a meat pot would or would not allow bitul, eating a food with a certain amount of dairy in it after a meat meal would or would not be allowed.

However, the main discussion on this matter would seem to involve the DE marking on some foods. The star-k link could be followed if needed.

As seen in the dairy equipment explanation from the COR, it is only allowed if there is **no** dairy whatsoever in the food being considered.This implies that if there is anything dairy in the second food (which would not be batel l'chatchilah because it is a deliberate ingredient) it cannot be eaten after a meat meal and would not be batel.

> As stated above, the pareve designation demarcates a product as having
>   neither diary nor meat ingredients. The DE designation which stands
>   for “Dairy Equipment” means that a hot product, while pareve in its
>   essence, has been manufactured using equipment that was also used to
>   manufacture hot dairy products where no kosherization occurred in
>   between. It is important to note that a thorough cleaning of the
>   equipment still occurs between production runs and there is absolutely
>   no dairy products contained in an item labeled DE. Thus, from the
>   standpoint of the kosher consumer, if someone has just completed a
>   meat meal, he may then eat a product labeled DE. He cannot however eat
>   something labeled DE during a meat meal. Some rabbis however are
>   stricter in this regard and consulting with one’s own rabbi for
>   personal guidance is always advisable.

As the [star-k](http://www.star-k.org/cons-faqs-status.htm) points out only items marked DE can be eaten in less than six hours and as the COR emphasizes, no item marked DE will have **any** dairy products in it.

Personally, from reading the COR description,
I would consider the sources involving a dairy product or a nonkosher product to a meat dish (making the meat dish nonkosher if deliberately added in a batel amount) similar to the halacha of eating a kosher food that has a deliberately added dairy ingredient. Thus, the analysis of if the second dish can be eaten would be similar to whether or not the mixture is forbidden.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question; non-kosher and kosher-but-dairy aren't necessarily the same

Comment: @Matt I will make the sentence that applies to the question bold. The point is that the mixing of the milk **deliberately** to be batel still applies.

Comment: @sabbahillel I don't think you followed Matt's comment. Your case is about milk in meat, not milk in pareve. You also are discussing a case where the intention was to nullify it, unlike the OP's case.

Comment: @DoubleAA The way I read the question is about whether a dairy ingredient added **deliberately** rather than by accident would be able to be considered pareve. That is why I added the reference to the DE description. Note that the DE must also be **intrisically pareve** rather than just having an amount that makes it batel had it been added by accident.

Comment: @sabbahillel It was added deliberately to the mix but not to nullify it (for 'texture' or something, assuming Maamid etc. is not an issue).

Comment: The paragraph you just added is your own opinion and you don't even offer any support for it. Why would there be a prohibition of Bittul Heter that there should be a Kenas for doing it??

Comment: @DoubleAA The fact that it was added to the mixture as a deliberate ingredient is what makes it a problem. The fact that the amount is less than the shiur is what makes it "batel l'chatchilah". A person does not deliberately add an ingredient for no other purpose than to make it batel.

Comment: @sabbahillel "The fact that it was added to the mixture as a deliberate ingredient is what makes it a problem." You are asserting that without basis... "A person does not deliberately add an ingredient for no other purpose than to make it batel." I don't really know what you mean to say, but certainly someone could have all sorts of reasons for adding something aside from trying to nullify it.

Comment: @DoubleAA Actually, I think that the fact that the COR allows eating the two items separately but **not** when the second food has any dairy ingredients in it is the main point. I will remove the other quotes and try to make that clearer.

Comment: @sabbahillel That's just the kashrut agency's common 'policy' not to rely on bittul ever. Nothing to do with halacha.